# Products and relationships of ideals of Ring R.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be a left ideal of $R$.

(a) Let $K$ be a left ideal of $R$. Show that $(IK)^{n} \subseteq I^{n}K$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

(b) Show that $I+ IR$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$.

For (a) I presume that it shouldnt take too much working out? Do I show that $IK$ is itself an ideal (product of left ideals is an ideal) and then show $(IK)^{n}$ is also?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** For (a) when $n = 3$ you would let $a_i \in I$ and $b_i \in K$.  Then $(IK)^3$ is generated by elements of the form $a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3 = a_1(b_1a_2)(b_2a_3)b_3$ and you would use that grouping to argue that $a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3 \in I^3K$.  You'll just have to write down that argument for a general $n$.

There's probably also an inductive proof but this one occurred to me first.

For (b) Note that $I + IR$ is automatically a left ideal because $I$ is a left ideal.  To show that $(I + IR)\cdot R \subseteq I + IR$ it's enough to show that $I \cdot R \subseteq I + IR$ and $IR \cdot R \subseteq I + IR$.

Comment: Thanks- So can the generators of $I^{3}$ be written in the form $a_1a_2a_3$?
and then the generators of $I^{3}K$ be written $(a_1a_2a_3)b_i$ ?

Comment: It's not necessarily the same $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s as in the answer, but yes, the generators of $I^3$ are all products of three elements from $I$ and the generators of $I^3K$ are all products of three elements from $I$ followed by one element from $K$.

Comment: For (b) do i need to show in terms of generators? how can i simply prove your first statement about it being a left ideal?Would saying J is a left ideal, JR is  a left ideal and the sum of left ideals is a left ideal? Thanks for the help

Comment: Both of those can be done by looking at generators.

Comment: quick reply! i edited while you typed.

Comment: Yes, those statements about $J$ would be a perfectly reasonable proof in my eyes.